# Cannot find referenced file after deploy C#

Tags: c#, file, solution, projects

We are trying to create a website verifier for our internal site, to verify that all sites are up. For this, we use seleniums chromedriver.

We have 2 projects for this:
1 main project which executes the code.
1 "shared" project, which is shared between all of our different solution. This project contains data, which is used across multiple solutions.

We have placed the chromedriver in the shared project, and initialize it like this:

```
        public static IWebDriver InitiateChromeDriver()
    {
        ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();

        option.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadPath);
        option.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");

        var path = Path.GetFullPath("Utility");

        Console.WriteLine(path);

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(path, option, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));

        return driver;
    }
```

This method is placed in the "Utility" folder, together with the Chromedriver.exe, and can run locally when debugging through Visual Studio.
When we deploy it to our production server, it cannot find the path to the chromedriver. The referenced path changes to C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Utility\chromedriver.exe on our production server.

What is a better approach at referencing the file, and ensuring that the path is correct?

Comment: A simple fix would be to store the path in the .Config file for the solution and then use it.

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that the path can change. We have several servers running different sites on the IIS, and not all of them run on the C:/ drive, so the path would change. Another thing that changes is the folder name, since we have previous versions stored.
When we deploy, the new folder name has the current timestamp of the deploy attached to it, so the folder name changes aswell.

Comment: Then you can try to make the installer save the path into a registry key (assuming it is an MSI or something similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below. Create a folder called drivers and add the chromedriver to it.

```
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                option.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
                driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.Combine(GetBasePath, @"Drivers\\"), options);


    public static string GetBasePath
    {
        get
        {
            var basePath =
                System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName((System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
            basePath = basePath.Substring(0, basePath.Length - 10);
            return basePath;
        }
    }
```